# How to get the specific label attached to a value/observation in a 'double' object

Tags: r, spss

Im wondering how to return or print the label attached to a specific value within a column of type "double".

I am able to see the full output of all observations, followed by a list of all the values and their corresponding labels, using

`list[[column]]`

My goal is to find a value in the column, thus far done using `list[column][row, ]` and then find the label associated with that numerical value, to eventually create a seperate table with each label, and the number of occurrences of values corresponding to said label.

I have checked that all responses are numerical, and the range is from 1 to 200ish.

`labels(list[column][row, ])` yields

```
[1] "1"

[[2]]
[1] "<column name>"
```

regardless of the number specified as 'row', which is not what I need. Apologies if this is a simple question, fairly new to R

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is in your list object

Comment: @algae the object expressed as list in my question appears to be more like a dataframe/tibble, as it is described in the environment tab as "300 obs. of 60 variables". However, using type_of (from rlang) states it is a list, and the elements within it are lists too. All elements in the 'list' are columns of sorts, with <dbl + lbl> or in some cases <chr> as their label. Is this what you mean?